# How to remove AddWsFederation() from DI?

Tags: testing, .net-core, ws-federation

I am trying to test my project which uses WsFederation for authentication.

In the main project I am setting up WsFederation normally:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
         .AddWsFederation(options =>
         {
             options.Wtrealm = appSettings.WsFederation.Wtrealm;
             options.MetadataAddress = appSettings.WsFederation.Metadata;
             options.CallbackPath = "/";
             options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
             options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
       {
           if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
           {
               if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
               {
                   ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
               }
               ctx.HandleResponse();
           }
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       };
         })
         .AddCookie();
```

For testing I am using a custom `WebApplicationFactory` where I add a simple Implementation of a `TestAuthHandler` (returning an authorized/unauthorized User).

```
 services.AddAuthentication(TestAuthHandler.Scheme)
               .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(TestAuthHandler.Scheme, options => { });
```

But if I return an Unauthorized user the WsFederation Authentication kicks in and fails, because for my Test Setup I don't have an Identity Provider configured (and I don't want to).

How can I reverse the `.AddWsFederation()` call so it is not in my DI anymore?

I have seen other question removing `PolicyEvaluators` like this:

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            // Disable WSFederation Authentication?
            //services.RemoveAll<WsFederationHandler>();
            services.RemoveAll<IPolicyEvaluator>();
        });
```

I tried to remove the WsFederationHandler but no luck so far.

Comment: Have you considered using an environment flag to determine if you add the auth to begin with when testing?

Comment: Well I don't really want to change my application to add an option to not authenticate at all. It just adds an option for failure.

Comment: You could try looking at the source code to see what they are actually doing and remove whatever they add https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation/WsFederationExtensions.cs,22

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the link I wrangled through some of the Functions and found a working way.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 2):

In the `WebApplicationFactory` you can replace the `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider` with an Implementation which has `WsFederation` removed.

```
// Create a Default Authenticator for Mocking
services
    .AddAuthentication(TestAuthHandler.Scheme)
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(TestAuthHandler.Scheme, options => { });

// Remove previous AuthenticationScheme Provider and replace by one without WsFederation
var authenticationSchemeProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>();
authenticationSchemeProvider.RemoveScheme(WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.RemoveAll<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>();
services.AddSingleton(authenticationSchemeProvider);
```